# How different are the OVA and movie versions of Time of Eve?

Tags: time-of-eve

What does one miss out from not watching either versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Contents that are exclusive to the OVA

They are mostly shown at the beginning of the following episodes:

- Episode 2: dori-kei commentary in the news
- Episode 3: Koji leaves his room and the discussion about sexroids on TV
- Episode 4: talk at Rikuo’s home about fuzzy logic and complaints at his dad’s office, and a short scene at the school with a girl classmate of Masaki making some cameo appearances

The ED song 「やさしい時間の中で」 is the vocal version of the piano piece played by Sammy at the Time of Eve. The epilogue following the ED has Naoko decorating Sammy's hair with flower petals.

### Contents that are exclusive to the movie

- Setoro reporting to Dr. Ashimori at the beginning of the movie
- The first Time of Eve android customer seen by Rikuo and Masaki enters a room, which is later revealed to be Shiotsuki and Nagi's home
- Sammy making her hair in front of a mirror
- Sammy's chkdsk slideshow scenes following the events of episode 3 of the OVA
- Sammy holding a sheet music and looking at the sleeping Rikuo before going off to play the piano at midnight
- A different ED song with accompanying sketches of Nagi's past
- Nagi talks to Shiotsuki in the epilogue